# Discord.py don't require space for tempmute command

Tags: discord.py

I have this code for my discord.py bot, for my tempmute command:

```
@bot.command()
async def tempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: int, d, *, reason=None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")
    if not mutedRole:
        mutedRole = await guild.create_role(name="Muted")

    for channel in guild.channels:
        await channel.set_permissions(mutedRole, speak=False, send_messages=False)
    for role in guild.roles:
        if role.name == "Muted":
            await member.add_roles(role)

            embed = discord.Embed(title="TempMuted!", description=f"{member.mention} has been tempmuted.", colour=discord.Colour.red())
            embed.add_field(name="Reason:", value=reason, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Time for the mute:", value=f"{time}{d}", inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

            if d == "s":
                await asyncio.sleep(time)

            if d == "m":
                await asyncio.sleep(time*60)

            if d == "h":
                await asyncio.sleep(time*60*60)

            if d == "d":
                await asyncio.sleep(time*60*60*24)

            await member.remove_roles(role)

            embed = discord.Embed(title="Unmute (temp mute expired) ", description=f"Unmuted -{member.mention} ", colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

            return
```

However, when using the command, it has to be typed like this: "!tempmute @user 10 m" if I wanted a 10 minute mute. Notice how it is "10 m". How would I make it so "10m" would work (without a space). So "!tempmute @user 10m"? If a user writes it without a space at the moment, the error "discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "int" failed for parameter "time"." occurs, probably as it isn't recognising a number with the letter at the end. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve this would be to create your own Converter and typehint the class in the argument. As documented [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#ext-commands-adv-converters)

So instead of converting your time in your command function, you would do it in the converter making the syntax more cleaner.

Example of a converter

```py
time_regex = re.compile(r"(\d{1,5}(?:[.,]?\d{1,5})?)([smhd])")
time_dict = {"h":3600, "s":1, "m":60, "d":86400}
class TimeConverter(commands.Converter):
    async def convert(self, ctx, argument):
        matches = time_regex.findall(argument.lower())
        time = 0
        for v, k in matches:
            try:
                time += time_dict[k]*float(v)
            except KeyError:
                raise commands.BadArgument(f"{k} is an invalid time-key! h/m/s/d are valid!")
            except ValueError:
                raise commands.BadArgument(f"{v} is not a number!")
        return time
```

This is an example of a Time converter, where it will use a regex and converts it into an int in seconds. Which accepts `<number><smhd>`, example `2d`.

The library calls TimeConverter().convert during the command invocation, hence we create a method called convert, which accepts Context object and arguments as str. All you have to do is return something, or raise an error if there is an error.

In order to use this, you would do it as follows

```py
@bot.command()
async def tempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: TimeConverter, *, reason=None):
    ...
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    await member.remove_roles(role)
    ...
```

The command invocation would be

`!tempmute @user 2d here's the reason`

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a tempmute command myself. I would say the command would work fine with a simple dictionary. If you want to convert time units a simple dictionary would do it and you wouldn't require a hell lot of code.

First I would add the code and then give a brief explanation.

### Code:

```
@MyBot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def tempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time, *, reason=None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if member.guild_permissions.administrator:
        ifadmin_embed = discord.Embed(title='Member is Administrator!', description=f'The user, {member.mention} can\'t be muted as he/she is an administrator.', color=0xff0000)
        ifadmin_embed.set_author(name='NucleoBot')
        ifadmin_embed.set_footer(text=ctx.author)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=ifadmin_embed, delete_after=10.0)

    else:
        if discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Muted'):
            muted_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Muted')
        else:
            perms = discord.Permissions(send_messages=False, add_reactions=False, connect=False, speak=False)
            await ctx.guild.create_role(name='Muted', permissions=perms)
            muted_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Muted')

        time_convert = {'s' : 1 , 'm' : 60 , 'h' : 3600 , 'd' : 86400, 'y' : 31536000}
        mute_time = int(time[0]) * time_convert[time[-1]]
        await ctx.message.delete()
        role_if_muted = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'Muted', ctx.guild.roles)

        if role_if_muted in member.roles:
            alreadymuted_embed = discord.Embed(title='Already Muted!', description=f'The user, {member.mention} is already muted for {mute_time} seconds.', color=0xff0000)
            alreadymuted_embed.set_footer(text=ctx.author)
            alreadymuted_embed.set_author(name='NucleoBot')
            await ctx.channel.send(embed=alreadymuted_embed, delete_after=10.0)
        else:
            if reason == None:
                await member.add_roles(muted_role)
                tempmuted_embed = discord.Embed(title='Temporary Mute Successfull!', description=f'{member.mention} has been muted for {mute_time} seconds successfully! \n \n Reason: No reason given.', color=0x4fff4d)
                tempmuted_embed.set_author(name='NucleoBot')
                tempmuted_embed.set_footer(text=ctx.author)
            else:
                await member.add_roles(muted_role)
                tempmuted_embed = discord.Embed(title='Temporary Mute Successfull!', description=f'{member.mention} has been muted for {mute_time} seconds successfully! \n \n Reason: {reason}', color=0x4fff4d)
                tempmuted_embed.set_author(name='NucleoBot')
                tempmuted_embed.set_footer(text=ctx.author)

        await ctx.channel.send(embed=tempmuted_embed, delete_after=10.0)
        await asyncio.sleep(mute_time)
        await member.remove_roles(muted_role)
```

### Explanation:

My code has almost everything here that you need for a mute command. Only the members with roles that have `manage_role` permissions to execute this command. Also if someone try to mute a member who is an administrator of the server, an embed would pop up to say, `Member is an admin`.

The code also has the aspect that if no reason is given it would not show any error but post an embed made for `No Reason` command, i.e., if no reason is mentioned. It also checks that if the server doesn't have a role named `Muted`. It the role exist it would simply use it otherwise first it would create a role named `Muted` with denial of important permissions and use it for the mute.

Now the time conversion. The line which is used for this:

```
time_convert = {'s' : 1 , 'm' : 60 , 'h' : 3600 , 'd' : 86400, 'y' : 31536000}
```

This command takes `second` as basic value for the conversion then converts every other unit in terms of seconds. Here `s` is equated to `1` and `m` is equated to `60` as I minute is equal to 60 seconds. Similarly doing that same with other units we derive everything to seconds. This dictionary turns everything to seconds and using `asyncio` we create a timer for mute.

---

Hope this helps, if you still get any doubt, please feel free to ask me.

Thank You!